# Removing an entity depends on many criterias

Tags: c#, architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design

We have a **Doc** entity which has a property called **ReportDate**. When user decides to remove a Doc we should check 30 conditions. These conditions are similar: we check 30 entities' **ReportDate** property is not equal to Doc's **ReportDate**.

It looks like a smell for me. Every Time we add new entity we should care to add new criteria for remove Doc.

Is it ok to have 30+ criterias for removing an entity? Any sample code or project really appreciated.

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstand something, there is a Doc related with 30+ another different entities via ReportDate, and you cannot remove Doc if there is at least one another entity referencing that ReportDate? Is any of those entities acting as an aggregate root? Are there any other rules of removing those entities, ex. removing entity X causes remove of Doc entity?

Comment: @pwc: `Doc.ReportDate` is a date time property. Non of 30+ related entities has direct reference to Doc, but there is a logic for removing a Doc that there should not exist any `relatedEntitiy.ReportDate  == Doc.ReportDate`. For some related entities may complex logics should be checked to know if user can remove Doc. For last question no, related entities don't know or depend to Doc entity and they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer basically is "It depends".

In Domain Driven Design (DDD), we strive to model the domain based on a common understanding of what actually occurs in the domain in which we are working, and how the application we develop will solve the *business* problems.

If, in the domain, there actually are 30+ references to `Doc` (either implicit or explicit, see below), then yes, it is correct to check those 30+ references before deleting the `Doc` entity. If these references are a result of an implementation detail which does not stem from the domain experts, then no, it is not correct to check those 30+ references. Are they really references, or simply a consequence of a design choice?

When performing the delete of any entity, you can check cross-aggregate conditions in a domain service, and report failure to delete if you find any `Related entity` which prevent the `Doc` from being deleted.

A sample implementation of this validation in service, could look like this:

```cs
public void DocDeletion.Delete(Doc doc)
{
    var relatedEntities = relatedEntityRepository.FindRelatedEntitiesWithReportDate(doc.ReportDate);

    if (relatedEntities.Any())
    {
        DomainEvents.Raise(new RelatedEntityPreventedDocDeletionEvent(doc, relatedEntities));
    }
    else
    {
        // Assumes docRepository.Delete raises relevant domain event
        docRepository.Delete(doc);
    }
}
```

I want to share a few thought which occured to me upon reading this question, but first a few assumptions:

1. `Doc` is an aggregate root
2. `Related entity` is an entity in another aggregate
3. `Related entity` cannot exists without a `Doc` entity/aggregate

Then it seems to me that you have an implicit reference between `Related entity` and `Doc`, i.e., for every `Related entity.ReportDate` there *must* exist a `Doc` with an equal `ReportDate`.

I think this relationship should be made more explicit, adding instead a direct reference to the aggregate root which holds the `Doc` (based on my assumptions, the aggregate root id of the `Doc` entity). This would also allow two `Related entity`s to reference two different `Doc`s with the same `ReportDate`, which may, or may not, be a requirement in your domain (ask the domain experts).

Either way,  the implicit reference between two aggregates are now explicit, and the `ReportDate` needs only be stored where it makes sense (either on `Doc` or on `Related entity`), or still on both, if it is the correct thing in the domain (though, this would probably imply that `Doc.ReportDate` is something else than `Related entity.ReportDate`, e.g., `Doc.FiledDate` and `Related entity.ReportedDate`).

And then, when you wish to delete your `Doc` entity, you have to validate across several aggregates. This type of validation is usually best placed in a domain service, which can access the repositories containing both the `Doc` entities and the `Related entity` entities, and make the decision whether or not to actually delete the `Doc` based on if it finds any related `Related entity`s which restrains the `Doc` from being deleted (e.g., matching `ReportDate` or a reference to the aggregate root `Doc`).

More details on validation/operation result reporting, can be found [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/15/validation-in-a-ddd-world/).